# How to send Cookie using PHP Goutte

Tags: php, curl, cookies, goutte

I have this code in PHP Goutte

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://www.yellowpages.com.au',
        'cookies' => true,
        'headers' =>  [
            'Accept'          => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'zip, deflate, sdch', 
            'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 
            'Cache-Control'   => 'max-age=0',
            'User-Agent'      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
        ]
    ]);
```

I want to send my custom Cookie to server

Usually I do it this way using simple cURL

```
$a_curl_opts = array(
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $file_cook,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $file_cook,
);
curl_setopt_array($curl_init, $a_curl_opts);
```

And I saw somewhere this thing to do in Goutte

```
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file_cook); 
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file_cook);
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\Ampps\www\gum\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php on line 87 and defined in D:\Ampps\www\gum\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php on line 126
```

Comment: This was a major help for me: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/pull/250#issuecomment-274504635

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array(
             'curl' => array(
                 CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file,
                 CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1
             ),
             'cookies' => true
         ));
```